# Problem executing grep from PHP using --exclude-dir option

Tags: php, grep

I'm trying to run a grep search from my PHP application and am having trouble with one of the options.  The grep command is as follows:

```bash
grep -rn --exclude-dir={img,node_modules,vendor} -E "14847"
```

This command returns the expected results. However, if I open PHP interactively and run this line:

```php
print `grep -rn --exclude-dir={img,node_modules,vendor} -E "14847"`;
```

I get results found within the `node_modules` directory.  Interestingly, if I remove the curly braces and commas and only exclude `node_modules`, then it works and excludes those results. I can also just list the `--exclude-dir` option separately for each directory to exclude (but let's ignore that for a moment). So it seems to be something with the handling of curly braces or commas.  I have tried escaping both with backslashes with no luck unfortunately.  Am I missing something in PHP's parsing of the execution operator?

Comment: What do you get for `print \`pwd\`;`? Is it what you expect?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what I expect.  And the results from the command in my post are all correct with respect to the current working directory.

Comment: I did similar tests. The behavior is the same as the colleague described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `{one,two,three}` notation is a bash-ism, it's not expanded by either PHP or grep. When you run a command in backticks from within PHP, it runs that program via sh, not bash. Thus, you lose the possibility to use this type of expansion. As a workaround, you can just specify `--exclude-dir` more than once:

```
print `grep -rn --exclude-dir=img --exlude-dir=node_module --exclude-dir=vendor -E "14847"`;
```

Comment: Backticked command is not run directly, it is run with a default command interpreter, which is usually `sh`. Run `<?php echo 'echo \$0';` (replace quotes by backticks)